# Different interfaces of a OpenWrt router with the same mac address?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router

Can someone explain me why different interfaces has all the same mac address?
Below eth0.1, eth0.2 and wlan0 has all the same mac address, is this normal?

```
ip link show eth0.1
6: eth0.1@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-lan state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 80:2a:a8:73:7d:39 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

ip link show eth0.2
7: eth0.2@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 80:2a:a8:73:7d:39 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

ip link show wlan0
4: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 80:2a:a8:72:7d:39 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: Typically this occurs when you have one Network card with different profiles and one connection to the Router.

Comment: So the mac address of the wireless interface wlan0 can have the same mac address as the ethernet interface eth0.1 en 0.2?

Comment: That should not be the case. I thought you had one card. Wireless card MAC will be different from LAN card MAC.  Check your setups carefully and use ifconfig details or other to see the MAC of the specific card.

Comment: I'm trying to understand my device before changing anything. The configuration is still default after install. Ifconfig gives no information about wlan0, Wireless is turned off by default.

Comment: If I do ifconfig wlan0 the MAC Address of the ethernet card is shown.

Comment: The MAC address is a physical part of the card and the MAC address may be on a label on the case. If it is not running, the OS may be confusing the information.

Comment: Router make and model please?

Comment: Ubiquiti Nanostation M5 xw OpenWRT 19.07.3

Comment: Can I say the MAC is physical so there is one for the radio whatever wireless client or master interfaces I define and there is one for ethernet (eth0) whatever vlans I have for WAN and LAN??